# Parsing single and double floating-points

Tags: c#, validation, floating-point

I'm currently implementing the parser for an object notation. The object notation must support single and double floating point values, suffixed by either F or D. Reading the pattern of floating-point value is easy, expressed as a regex that would be:

```
-?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+([Ee][1-9]+)?
```

The difficult part is validating the size of a floating-point string representation since my attempt to understand floating-points numbers failed more or less. Since there might be dozens of floating-point values, I do not want to use the TryParse method, I want to call Parse while being sure that the string is in the right range.

Comment: What exactly is your question and your proposed solution, and why doesn't it work?

Comment: Can't you just use `Double.parse` and `Single.parse`?

Comment: @ORMapper My question is how to validate strings that represent a floating-point value. I can't figure out a reliable solution since I do not understand how the decimal form of floating-point number relates to the binary form.

Comment: "Reading the pattern of floating-point value is easy" No, it is not. Try your pattern on `2e-3`. Also, `2D` and `3F` should be valid; your pattern would reject these as well.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The regex was just an example, I'm not actually using it so I excluded the suffix on purpose.

Comment: Did you try reading the [`Double.Parse()` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt.aspx) to see the accepted pattern of the default number style?

Comment: @CodeCaster I tried but it doesn't. For example, it returns an exception for `"340282360000000000000000000000000000000"`.

Comment: Every decimal number can be mapped to a `float` (resp. `double`). 1.0E-999999999999999999999 can be mapped to `0.0`. 1.0E999999999999999999999 can be mapped to `+inf`. What “right range” are you trying to validate?

Comment: **Why** don't you want to use `TryParse`?

Comment: @PascalCuoq 0 to 3.402823e38 for positive values and 1 to 3.402823e38 for negative values. I try to validate both standard and scientific notation.

Comment: @ClickRick Because I'm in a state of ignorance and I try to understand floating-point decimal representations.

Comment: @toplel32 You can always normalize every positive decimal representation to D.DDDDDDDDDDDD…eE (converting the natural representation DDDDDDD to that one isn't difficult, nor is DDDD.DDDeE. Once this is done, a number is too large if E > 38 or if E == 38 and (the first digit is more than 3 or the first digit is 3 and (the second digit is more than 4 or …)).

Comment: @PascalCuoq Thanks that makes sense. I'll try to implement that for scientific form. For standard form, I figured that a value is valid if the integer part doesn't exceed `"340282350000000000000000000000000000000"`. So I would iterate over the string and check if the ASCII position is less or equal than the digit in the maxvalue string.